# How to show names of missing variables rowwise?

Tags: r, missing-data

I do have a problem, which I can not solve alone. Sorry I am a newbie, and I have tried many different things already.
I do have a dataframe with 23 participants and 40 variables. I want to produce a new text file saying WHICH variables are missing for each participant. What I did is:

```
miss_val=vector(mode='list',length=num_participants)
for ( i in 1:num_participants){
  miss_val[i]=sum(is.na(data[i,]))
}
```

which gives me the sum of missing values for each participant. Now I want to produce one sentence for each particopant specifying which variables are missing. I have used `which(is.na(data[i,])` which only gives me the positions of the different missing values--How can I get the names? I have also tried: `colnames( which( is.na (data[i,])` and it does not work either.

Comment: How about sharing some data?

Comment: Try  `res<-which(is.na(data),arr.ind=TRUE);split(res[,2],res[,1])`. This is just a wild guess; you should provide a sample of your data to have a more helpful answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without a great view of what your data looks like, it is difficult to assess.  However, you may try the sapply() function. This function can loop through variables in a data frame and return a list object, which is quite flexible in terms of what it stores. Here is an example that might fit your scenario:

```
# construct silly data.frame
temp <- data.frame("a"=1:10, "aa"=rep(1:5, 2), "b"=rnorm(10), 
"c"=sample(c("good", "bad", "ugly"), 10, replace=TRUE))
# build in some missing values
temp$a[c(1,5)] <- NA
temp$b[c(3,7, 9)] <- NA
temp$c[c(2,5)] <- NA
# take a peek at the data
temp
# construct empty list to store names of missing vars
missingVars <- list()
# loop through observations
for(i in 1:nrow(temp)) {
  # subset to one row data set
  obs.row <- temp[i,]
  # fill in missing var list with names of variables that are missing
  missingVars[[paste0("obs.",i)]] <- 
    names(obs.row)[unlist(sapply(obs.row, is.na))]
}
```

This should work given what you have described. You can then extract the names of the missing variables either by using the row number:

```
missingVars[[1]]
```

or by using the name of the list element:

```
missingVars[["obs.1"]]
```

would both extract the names of missing variables for the first observation.

Answer (score 0):

No data is provided, but you might try this:

```
 apply(dat, 1, function(x) { list(names(x)[ is.na(x) ] } )
```

The result will not be a dataframe but rather a list whose n-th entry will have character values that are the column names of missing elements by row.

```
> dat <- data.frame( x=c(NA, 1:4),y=c("a",NA,"b","c","d"), z=c( NA, 1:3,NA))
> apply(dat, 1, function(x) { list(names(x)[ is.na(x) ]) } )[[1]]
[[1]]
[1] "x" "z"

> apply(dat, 1, function(x) { list(names(x)[ is.na(x) ]) } )
[[1]]
[[1]][[1]]
[1] "x" "z"


[[2]]
[[2]][[1]]
[1] "y"


[[3]]
[[3]][[1]]
character(0)


[[4]]
[[4]][[1]]
character(0)


[[5]]
[[5]][[1]]
[1] "z"
```

I suppose one might also think about `sapply` or `lapply` on the column names which might then be `cbind()`-ed with `do.call`. This is what I came up with:

```
 do.call(cbind, lapply(names(dat) , function (x) c(NA,x)[ 1+is.na(dat[[x]]) ] ))
     [,1] [,2] [,3]
[1,] "x"  NA   "z" 
[2,] NA   "y"  NA  
[3,] NA   NA   NA  
[4,] NA   NA   NA  
[5,] NA   NA   "z"
```

Needed to add 1 to the results of is.na applied column-wise to create an index to choose either the column name or NA.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming data as the following:

```
    particpant       var1       var2
  1          1 0.74261292  0.2699047
  2          2 0.08523502 -0.2588741
  3          3         NA  1.3995776
  4          4 0.12567631  0.8855174
  5          5 0.44244614 -0.3241024
```

And i is the current participant to check for missing vars:

```
i <- 3
```

You could use colnames in the following way to get the name of the column that is NA. Notice the usage of colnames. The parameter is the whole dataset, and then we index into the vector with the return value of the which function:

```
colnames(data)[which(is.na(data[i,]))]
```

Which would output:

```
[1] "var1"
```